# Object key mapping based on condition not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

I have tried below code but don't work:

```
Object.keys(singleproductdetails).map(function(detail, id) {                                                                
return (
  <div>
    <ul className="list-inline">
      <li>{detail} <span>:</span></li>
      {
        id == 12 ?
          <li>
            <p>
              <a
                href={'http://' + singleproductdetails[detail]} 
                target="_blank"
                style={{color: "#1e1e80"}}>
                {singleproductdetails[detail]}
              </a>
            </p>
          </li> :
          <li><p>{singleproductdetails[detail]}</p></li>
      }
    </ul>
  </div>
})
```

I am trying to give link to particular key but I am unable to do that

Comment: Can you provide the `singleproductdetails` var as well? Than we can see what's going on :)

Comment: If you are "unable to do that", what is happening?

Comment: Maybe try === instead of ==

Comment: your `id` is really an index, are you sure you always want the 13th item in the `singleproductdetails` object?

Comment: If you could provide the `singleproductdetails` Object, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: i always want 13th item to be given a tag with link as above code

Comment: @AlbertoPerez it is an object

Comment: Yeah, my bad, but could you provide de Object snippet above? In order to check what's going on.

Comment: attached object

Comment: Thanks, but you don't have to replace the previous snippet, just add the object.

Comment: can anyone guide me

Comment: If you make your question clearer by editing it to add more details, yes

Comment: I have an object with object.keys I am showing dynamically,  index 12 I want the value to be shown in anchor tag as URL

Comment: if its just that your link isn't working, then it is because the `Product url` key already has `//` prepended. You are adding it in href as well. Additionally add a key attribute to your div element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the following: Your mapping an `Object` and them returning the UI that you want to render, but the `map` method, in that case, returns an `Array` of `Objects` (That are what you want to show), so you need to read that array in order to display de UI, for Example:

```
const UI = Object.keys(singleproductdetails).map(function(detail, id) {                                                                
return (
  <div>
    <ul className="list-inline">
      <li>{detail} <span>:</span></li>
      {
        id == 12 ?
          <li>
            <p>
              <a
                href={'http://' + singleproductdetails[detail]} 
                target="_blank"
                style={{color: "#1e1e80"}}>
                {singleproductdetails[detail]}
              </a>
            </p>
          </li> :
          <li><p>{singleproductdetails[detail]}</p></li>
      }
    </ul>
  </div>
});
```

And them, in your `render` method (An example):

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>{UI}</div>
  )
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rym9h9) is a StackBlitz showing exactly what I'm talking about..

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(singleproductdetails).map(function(detail, id) {                                                                
return (
  <div>
    <ul className="list-inline">
      <li>{detail} <span>:</span></li>
      {
        (id == 12) ?
         `<li>
            <p>
              <a
                href={'http://' + singleproductdetails[detail]} 
                target="_blank"
                style={{color: "#1e1e80"}}>
                {singleproductdetails[detail]}
              </a>
            </p>
          </li>` :
          `<li><p>{singleproductdetails[detail]}</p></li>`
      }
    </ul>
  </div>
})
```

Comment: no, I am unale to get same old is coming

Comment: What have you changed? Why have you changed?

Comment: not expected output